# jQuery: How do I not hide a section with anchor in url

Tags: jquery, anchor

On my page most p-sections under a h3-heading are hidden. If you click on them, the content beneath is shown. Only the first section is shown when the page is opened. I use jQuery to hide these section like:

```
jQuery("#area h3:first").addClass("active");
jQuery("#area p:not(:first)").hide();
```

But what, if there is an anchor in one of the other section and the user is linking to it with a # at the end of the url? Right now, it jumps to the hidden section, which is irritating, because the text is not shown. I would not like to hide the section when an anchor in the url is within this section e.g. http://domain.com/page.php#anchor_in_section_3.

How do I prevent the section to hide/collapse?

Detail:
After answer 1 I found two problems: If you use .hide and a .show just one line of code later, the sections remains hidden. That seems to fast for jQuery.
The other problem is, that with the solution described in answer 1 jQuery only finds the anchor, if it is not in a child tag.

It is more difficult than I thought :)

So the solution described in words is, that all sections except the first and the one containing the anchor tag should be hidden. The anchor can be in any (child)-tag of the section.

Tried 2 hours to transfer this into jQuery but without success with my poor jQuery-knowledge.

Comment: I've updated my answer to address these issues, and added a live demo.  See below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the name of the anchor from the URL, use the following line:

```
var anchorName = document.location.hash.substring(1)
```

That retrieves the hash portion of the URL, then trims the first character out (the first character will always be the hash symbol, "#").  Here's some documentation on that: [Javascript Tutorial, Location.hash](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/JavaScript/0320__Location/Locationhash.htm). Once you have that, do something like the following:

```
jQuery("#area p:has(a[name=" + anchorName + "])").show();
```

This will show any paragraph in `#area` that contains an anchor with the name specified in the URL's hash portion.

**EDIT**

To solve the problem of jQuery being to fast, you can use a fancier selection to only hide the ones that will end up hidden, like so:

```
$("#area > p:not(:first)").filter("p:not(:has(a[name=" + anchorName + "]))").hide();
```

That says to take all paragraphs except the first one, then take the subset of those that don't contain an anchor with a given value for the `name` attribute, and hide whatever remains.  The first paragraph, and any that contain an anchor with the give name will remain visible.

Here is a live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/JDQxP/

Because we can't get the hash from the URL on jsFiddle, I've replaced that line with static values.  Uncomment them one at a time to see the effect of each.  Note that the "phasellus" anchor is in a wrapper span, but the selector still works properly on it.

Comment: Thank you!

I found two problems: If you use .hide and a .show just one line of code later, the sections remains hidden. That seems to fast for jQuery. The other problem is, that with this solution only finds the anchor, if it is not in a child tag.

It is more difficult than I thought :)

So the solution described in words is, that all sections except the first and the one containing the anchor tag should be hidden. The anchor can be in any (child)-tag of the section.

Tried 2 hours to transfer this into jQuery but without success with my poor jQuery-knowledge.

Comment: According to the :has() selector documentation, it checks all descendants, not just direct children.  See it here: http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/

Comment: One additional Question: I now see, that if the section with an anchor in it is not hidden, the h3-heading above it should have the css class "active". How do I do this?
Last questions: where do I find your amazon wishlist on your website? :)

Comment: Onto the end of the statement from the last edit, add the following: '.end().filter(':visible').prev('h3').addClass("active")'  See this modified demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9rZaG/  And gratitude is quite sufficient a reward :)